# Inserção de dados em Modal Bootstrap com PHP OO

Tags: php, jquery, orientação-a-objetos, modal, crud

Estou desenvolvendo uma tela de cadastro de clientes com PHP OO mas devido à minha inexperiência estou encontrado dificuldades em listar os dados do cliente dentro de uma Modal Bootstrap.

**Primeiramente, tenho essa lista de Objetos Cliente onde apresento apenas alguns dados básicos dos clientes cadastrados:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
**Código:**

```
     <?php
              foreach ($cliente->buscarClientes() as $key => $value){
                echo "<tr>
                    <td><input type='checkbox' value='$key'</td>
                    <td>".$value->getNome()."</td>
                    <td>".$value->getCpf()."</td>
                    <td>".$value->getEmail()."</td>
                    <td>".$value->getDataCadastro()."</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalCliente' data-clientmodal='$key'><i class='fa fa-edit' title='Editar'> </i></a>
                        <a href='#'> <i class='fa fa-trash' title='Excluir'> </i> </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>";
              }
            ?>
```

Obs: buscarClientes() retorna um Array de objetos Cliente onde o índice é o ID do cliente.

**Modal:**[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Codigo Jquery da modal Bootstrap:**

```
   <script>
        $(function () {

          // Modal editar/inserir cliente
          $('#modalCliente').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
            var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
            var recipient = button.data('clientmodal') // Extract info from data-* attributes

            var modal = $(this)
            if(recipient !== null){ 
              modal.find('.modal-title').text('Editar Cliente (#' + recipient + ")")
              modal.find('.modal-body input#modal-idml').val("example")
            } else {

               modal.find('.modal-title').text('Novo cliente')
            } 

          })

        });
  </script>
```

Gostaria de que ao usuário apertar no ícone do lápis a Modal abrisse com todos os dados do respectivo cliente para poder editá-los, se possível reaproveitando o objeto que já está criado. Tentei utilizar AJAX de algumas formas, mas não entendi como utilizá-lo para esse fim.

Poderiam me ajudar e se possível exemplificar como faço isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma dica de como eu faria se entender conseguirá fazer do seu jeito , eu criaria uma nova pasta com um arquivo php -> "dados.php" e ao clicar no botão pra abrir a modal .

```
var acess;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
acess = new XMLHttpRequest();

}

else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
acess = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}


var url = "pasta/dados.php?userID="+ID;
acess.open("GET", url, true);
acess.onreadystatechange = function() {
if(acess.readyState == 1) {
document.getElementById('modal').innerHTML = 'Carregando ...';
}

if(acess.readyState == 4 && acess.status == 200) {

var answer = acess.responseText;

document.getElementById('modal').innerHTML = answer;

}
}
acess.send(null);
```

assim no dados.php você coloca os dados do usuário , recebe o ID faz a consulta e retorna os dados , e essa pagina vai ser processada dentro do elemento com ID "modal" ou o ID que você determinou pra sua modal

```
//DADOS.PHP
<?php
$userID = $_GET['userID']??"";
if($userID != ""){
$cliente = $con->query("SELECT Username,Cpf,Email,Data FROM TABELA User WHERE UserID = $userID")


foreach ($cliente->buscarClientes() as $key => $value){
            echo "<tr>
                <td><input type='checkbox' value='$key'</td>
                <td>".$value->getNome()."</td>
                <td>".$value->getCpf()."</td>
                <td>".$value->getEmail()."</td>
                <td>".$value->getDataCadastro()."</td>
                <td>
                    <a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalCliente' data-clientmodal='$key'><i class='fa fa-edit' title='Editar'> </i></a>
                    <a href='#'> <i class='fa fa-trash' title='Excluir'> </i> </a>
                </td>
            </tr>";
          }
}
?>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, entendi a forma que você fez e consegui passar isso para meu código, ficou ótimo